# Echoing database colum with ñ character in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, wampserver

Why can I echo `ñ` without a problem in a PHP program on my PC with Windows 7 and wamp 2.4, but on my main server with Windows Server 2008 and wamp 2.4, it prints another character like `Ã‘` (sometimes with diamonds)? How do I solve this problem?

Note I'm using the same browser specs anď wamp server specs in both computers running the same program.

Comment: The browsers use the same encoding and charset ?

Comment: They have țhe same browser.  Does it mean I have to change my users' browser  who will access my site who has incompatible char set?

Comment: The server will need indicate the character encoding in the response, so the browser can display it with the correct charset. Example sending header from PHP `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`, example in your html `<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`.

Comment: If you use IE, you can right click and change the encoding.